# PHP Paypal Subscription

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I wish to create a subscription system on my site. But when i look at paypals subscriptions button, there is an option to take my customers back to some success url, say http://www.example.com/index.php?success=1, which is static and makes no sense at all, because then a free member who hasnt paid for the subscription can visit this link and have his account upgraded. I dont get it. Am i missing something? How do variables work here?

Answer (score 0):

The success URL would simply be some sort of a thank you page or receipt page letting the customer know they have successfully signed up.

To actually deliver the details about accessing their paid content areas I would recommend using [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to send email notifications and update your database accordingly.

PayPal provides a [bare-bones IPN template](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) you could get started with.  I have a [simple IPN solution](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn-php-template/) you may be interested that is pretty old now, but still very useful and I know lots of people like to use it as a starting point for IPN projects.

If you happen to be using WordPress you can get up and running quickly with the [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) plugin.